# Windows Batch file to run executable with different input file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-files

I'm really new to batch scripting, so please be patient! 
In windows xp I have an executable which has `input.in` and `output.out` files.
I would like to create a batch which reads the input file, modifies one or more lines, runs the `.exe` and stores the output in a folder whose name is dependent on the change made to the input file.

Say I have an input file with 4 lines like this:

```
32.0d0 ! first parameter
54.0d5 ! second parameter
1.5d-1 ! third parameter
11.0d0 ! fourth parameter
```

and I want to change the second parameter in the range 0.0->1.0 with step 0.1:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ReplaceLine1=2
set inpfile=input.in
set tempfile=input.temp
set increment=0.1
if exist "%tempfile%" del "%TempFile%"
for /L %%i in (1,1,11) do (
set /A param_value=(%%i-1)*increment
set /A Cnt2=0
for /f %%a in (%inpfile%) do (
set /A Cnt2+=1
if !Cnt2! geq %ReplaceLine1% echo %param_value% >> "%tempfile%" else echo %%a >> "%tempfile%"
)
copy /y "%tempfile%" "%inpfile%"
MD .\"param_value"
executable.exe < "%tempfile%" >> .\"param_value" 
)
```

does the above have any chance to get me somwhere close to where I would linke to go?

Answer (score 1):

You'll face a fundamental problem that batch-maths deals ONLY with integers...

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET line=%1
SET start=%2
SET inc=%3
SET end=%4
IF NOT DEFINED end ECHO require line#, start, increment, end&GOTO :EOF 
SET inpfile=input.IN
SET tempfile=input.temp
FOR /L %%i IN (%start%,%inc%,%end%) DO (
 IF EXIST "%tempfile%" DEL "%tempfile%"
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN ('find /n /v "" ^<%inpfile%') DO (
  IF %%a==%line% (
  SET value=%%i
  SET value=!value:~0,-1!.!value:~-1!
  IF .%%i==!value! SET value=0!value!
  >>%tempfile% ECHO !value!
  ) ELSE (>>%tempfile% ECHO %%b)
 )
MD .\!value!
COPY %tempfile% .\!value!\inputdata.
)
```

I'm assuming that your input file does NOT contain the `!comment` and that no line commences `"]"` or `"["`

I'm simply copying the tempfile constructed to the file `inputdata.` in the new directory created. No doubt in your application you would replace this with `executable.exe < "%tempfile%" >> .\"!value!\`**`resultfilename`**`" (noting that your output will be to a FILE not a DIRECTORY...)

Comment: If POWERSHELL is an option, it supports floating point data types.  And I believe it comes with newer Win versions and is obtainable free for XP.  <http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx>

Comment: @Peter WrightThanks for quick answer!!
i'm studying the code: i guess the instruction SET value=!value:~0,-1!.!value:~-1! is there to deal with the real numbering....right? can you give details on what it's doing please?

Comment: Batch ALWAYS works on strings. The mathematical functions work on strings-of-numerics converted to numeric representations then converted back to strings again. `%var%` represents the value of the variable `var` When a FOR command is encountered, the entire command is parsed, from the FOR to the closing parenthesis terminating the DO, which may be many lines away. As part of that procedure, `%var%` is replaced by the then-current value of `var` - that is, the PARSE-TIME value.

Comment: When `DELAYEDEXPANSION` mode is invoked by a `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` statement, then `!var!` is evaluated as the RUN-TIME value of `var` - that is, as it changes during the `FOR` loop. The syntax `!var:~m,n!`is evaluated as the substring length `n` characters starting at character `m` of `var`. If `m` or `n` is negative, it refers to the character-count from the END of the string `var`. Hence `value=!value:~0,-1!.!value:~-1!` sets value to (its current value from the start (position "0") to 1 character from the end) + . + (the current value from 1 short of the end to the end)

Comment: For more info on substringing in batch see `SET /?` from the prompt.